# Приставка "со": может ли она слиться с корнем слова?

Tags: этимология, лексика, морфемика, приставка, корень-слова

Думаю, что в словах *сосед* и *сочетание* "со" — это приставка. Но каков же тогда смысл корней "сед" и "чет"? Во втором случае вспоминается несколько устаревшее слово "чета", т. е. пара.

Может быть, в этих словах приставка уже слилась с корнем (такое, кажется, бывает)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно все. Сочетание < со + чета, сосед < со + сед (сидеть, селиться) - совместно живущий. Сравните еще: союз < со + уза, соперник < со+перечить, согласие - со + глас и проч. (знак < читается "порождено", "выведено").   
Что там с чем слилось - это уже философия. Неохота всуе пускаться в эти академические дебри.  В историческом плане "со" - приставка, причем очень продуктивная (до сих пор) и семантически ёмкая.

Comment: Что-то не вспомню, чтобы чередовались гласные -сид-/-сед-

Comment: Сидел - седло.  
"Чередование" - это оставьте для школы.    
В таких древних словах гораздо более сложные процессы могут происходить.

ЗЫ Зато я хорошо это "чередование" запомнил. С него началась моя лютая ненависть к русскому языку. В первом же классе я получил дврйку именно за предложение проверить "сидел" словом "сел". Мозгов у учителки не хватело понять, что я всего лишь намекаю на некорректность правила. Только слов ещё таких не знаю.

Answer (score -2):

(Социопат, совесть) значение слов меняется, вместе с изменчивостью общества (социума)

Comment: Еще бы понять, что Вы имели в виду... Разве в слове _социопат_  "со-" - приставка?

Comment: Началась ненависть? И до сих пор?